# How can "@" symbol be used for Excel/CSV Injection?

Tags: csv, code-injection

I was reading an article on Injection and there it was mentioned to check for cell data beginning with '=' , '+' , '-' and '@' symbols to prevent common injection attacks.

I could find why + , = , - could be a problem but couldn't find any information on '@' symbol!

Can someone please tell me what can the '@' symbol do and why should it be checked to prevent Excel/CSV Injection Attacks.

Comment: That strongly depends on the system, where the CSV is imported to ...

Comment: Seems like an Excel problem, where these can start formulas.

Comment: @siride What can the '@' symbol be used to start in Excel or CSV ?